# Visual Studio Code: Run-on-save extension not loading virtual enviornment to path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv, python-venv

I have the emerald walk run-on-save extension installed in Visual Studio Code.

I have set it to automatically format code when I save in the `.vscode/settings.json`, using black:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "app"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": ".py",
                "cmd": "pipenv run black ${file} && pipenv run isort ${file} && pipenv run black ${file}",
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

However it doesnt work. I have pipenv installed in a virtual environment, which I use for the workspace, but the $PATH being used by run-on-save doesnt include the path to the bin folder in the virtual environment.

How to I get run-on-save to load the virtual environment before running so that it picks up pipenv?

Comment: I haven't tried this extension before. Can you introduce its differences from   adding `"python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,` to `settings.json`.

Comment: I tried to install this extension and created a new virtual environment, but I didn't encounter any problems when saving. Could you please paste the error report?

Comment: No error report - just says it can't find the pipenv executable. Managed to fix it by sourcing the environment in the "cmd" used before the call to black with pipenv. Though I didn't have to do this on a different machine, which is strange.

Comment: Have you try to reinstall pipenv by command `pip uninstall pipenv` then `pipi install pipenv`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to load my virtual environment. Assuming your `$PATH` is in your `.bashrc`, you can run `source .bashrc` before your `pipenv` commands.

```
"commands": [
    {
        "match": ".py",
        "cmd": "source ~/.bashrc && pipenv run black ${file} && pipenv run isort ${file} && pipenv run black ${file}",
    }
]
```